# Should .com be included in tag names?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think that for well known services (e.g. `[amazon]`, `[gmail]`, `[ebay]`, etc) we don't need the `.com` as part of the tag name, but for lesser known services, especially those that can be confused with something else, we should have the `.com` as part of the tag name (e.g. `[geni.com]`, `[hunch.com]`, `[mint.com]`, `[ancestry.com]`,  etc.).

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 3):

Good idea, and once the lesser known sites become more well known then you can just do a tag merge and drop the .com from them as well.