# Where is [microsoft] appropriate?

Tags: support, tags

The Usage guide for [microsoft](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) is:

> Microsoft is an American company based in Redmond, Washington, with locations all over the world, that develops, licenses and sells a variety of software and products, from Windows to Office to Xbox to Windows Phone.

Is it appropriate for the following questions where it has been applied?:

Sync Exchange Calendar and Google Calendar
Why do Microsoft websites default to Polish on my work network?
I hit a bug when trying to report a bug regarding Visual Studio to connect.microsoft.com
How to quickly search for a specific MSKB article on microsoft.com?
Why do Microsoft and LinkedIn text me from the same number?
Microsoft Equivalent of Google Apps for Business (Email)
How can I migrate Documents from MS Office Live to Google Docs?
Export Exchange emails to Google Apps accounts?
Transfer MSN Live ID

UPDATE: Based on answers here to date the above list is now about half the length it was at first, mainly just by removal of [microsoft](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) tags. It seems to me likely that [microsoft](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) is not appropriate for any of the above either but in some cases may be a substitute for a more appropriate tag that does not yet exist, or the question is one that should be closed as off topic on the grounds of "no longer available". However with regard to "no longer available" I am confused by name changes.

Comment: There are some question that aren't a good fit for this site, like asking about two companies/web apps (i.e. Microsoft and LinkedIn) in same question, asking to find a web application for the user (i.e. Microsoft equivalent to...), among others.

Comment: Then several of those questions should be closed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a single circumstance where that tag is useful. One could make an argument that it could be used for questions about multiple Microsoft web applications at once, but I can't see how something like that wouldn't be too broad. More than likely one might have a question about a suite (aka, Office Online), but then we have a tag for that.

The only other use I can think of is for a Microsoft web application that doesn't already have a tag, but that's easy enough to fix anyway.

I say it should be burninated.

Comment: [tag:apple] is virtually the same, but it's on many fewer questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [microsoft](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) could be used for questions about using https://www.microsoft.com since users could sign-in, check a shopping cart, use the Microsoft search engine to search about Microsoft content.

By the other hand I think that it should not be used together with [office-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-online) or other similar tags for the same reasons explained on [Please don't double tag Google items](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/540/88163).

---

Side note:

Nowadays web sites of major software companies include features that make them look as a web app like sign-up, shopping company products, etc.

I'm wondering if we should use domain for tags (apple.com, microsoft.com,  google.com, yahoo.com, etc.) in order to make clear for newbies that questions on Web Applications should be about specific web applications, not about companies, customer service, and not for asking to find a web app from a company on behalf of the asker. By the other side tags like [microsoft](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft), [apple](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple) have very few questions, so perhaps we should not worry about this.

Related:

[Should .com be included in tag names?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/542/88163)

Comment: @pnuts After reading your question I'm wondering if it could be a good idea to use actual domain names for tags

Comment: @pnuts: I didn't mean TLDs, I meant web app domains. I think that "Google" is an edge case, because [tag:google-search] use www.google.com and their variants as its landing page in contrast to Microsoft.

Comment: A question about using microsoft.com, if it can even be considered a web application, would be better tagged with [tag:microsoft.com].